# Why the entry-Variable doesn't exists after search?

Tags: search, entry, form

I created a search form in my navigation and as it is described in the documentation, I created an search/results.html. And actually it works so far.

Now comes the problem: The results.html extends the "_base.html" and in this file I set the meta properties like this:

```
{% if entry.seoPageTitle is defined and entry.seoPageTitle != null %}
  {% set metaTitle = entry.seoPageTitle %}
{% else %}
  {% set metaTitle = entry.title %}
{% endif %}
```

and the HTML:

```
<title>{{ metaTitle }}</title>
```

And also this works so far.

But in combination it doesn't work. When I tipe in a Word in my Searchform and click "Search", then it gets "Variable "entry" does not exist". How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeh this a common problem I've run into as well.

The issue is the `entry` variable only gets set when Craft is routing to an entry that's created in the CMS. Since you're [routing](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/routing.html) directly to a template, Craft can't populate the variable.

I can think of a couple workarounds:

If your search form page is defined in the CMS, just grab that (or another page):

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('whatever').slug('search').one() %}
```

Another option is just to modify your code for fallbacks:

```
{% if entry is defined %}

    {% if entry.seoPageTitle is defined and entry.seoPageTitle != null %}
      {% set metaTitle = entry.seoPageTitle %}
    {% else %}
      {% set metaTitle = entry.title %}
    {% endif %}

{% else %}

    {# set the fallback from a global for example #}
       {% set metaTitle = defaults.metaTitle %}

{% endif %}
```

That's a lot of code for basically setting variables. What you could do to help clean this up is to use the [null-coa­lesc­ing operator](https://straightupcraft.com/events/twigs-null-coalescing-operator) or [`default` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/default.html) in Twig:

```
{% if entry is defined %}
      {% set metaTitle = entry.seoPageTitle|default(entry.title) %}
{% else %}
      {# set the fallback from a global called "defaults" as an example #}
      {% set metaTitle = defaults.metaTitle %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You made my day :)
I tried the "Another option" and it works now. 
Now I try to clean it up with your third proposal.

Comment: @ChuckLean You bet. If it worked for you, feel free mark it the accepted answer.